# Coinbase customer service

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, coinbase.com

Does anyone know how to get a hold of a human being on the phone at coinbase? Or the contact info of a good crypto lawyer? Their customer support is lacking. I have a stuck transaction going on two weeks with them. I'm worried they are going to change my coinbase receiving address on me and just steal my transaction.

Comment: Hi Dave, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Please note that customer service questions are off-topic here.

Comment: Hi @dave is your deposit TX confirmed on the blockchain?

Comment: Hello Dave, please stop repeating the same questions. Instead, please edit your question to provide more information as you go through related questions and clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: No, blockchain.info doesn't even recognize the hash. Sry but I just want the community to be aware of crypto companies performances out there. Don't want this to happen to someone else.